# Refind doesn't see refind.conf

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, bootloader, refind

I have Ubuntu and Windows 10 dual boot set up on my laptop. After booting and updating Windows 10, Windows resets the EFI boot order. To restore refind as my primary boot option I used to boot from a refind USB drive into Ubuntu and restore my EFI configuration. But today when I tried booting into the refind USB stick, I got this error:

```
ASSERT /usr/local/UDK2014/MyWorkSpace/MdePkg/Library/BaseMemoryLib/CopyMemWrapper.c(56): (Length - 1) <= (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL - (UINTN)DestinationBuffer)
ASSERT /usr/local/UDK2014/MyWorkSpace/MdePkg/Library/BaseMemoryLib/CopyMemWrapper.c(57): (Length - 1) <= (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFULL - (UINTN)SourceBuffer)
```

At first I thought it was the USB stick, since I had modified its controller, but after creating a new one I got the same error. From an Ubuntu USB stick I backed up my old EFI configuration and since `efibootmgr` didn't list refind, I reinstalled it. After a reboot refind tells me:

> Configuration file 'refind.conf' missing!

although the refind.conf exists. I tried using the provided refind-sample.conf instead of mine but it still doesn't work. Do you have a clue why this happens and more importantly how to fix it? Do you need any further information?

Comment: ReFind support: https://sourceforge.net/projects/refind/support

Comment: Why are you using rEFInd?

Comment: On Legacy Systems I used Grub. Grub is a great piece of sofware but lacks as far as I know a gui. I found refind felt very "flexible" since it also autodetects live usb sticks, etc. While Grub on an EFI system was still Grub. Don't get me wrong, Grub is rock-solid and great, but it just appeared to me that refind is more "modern", more EFI rather than Legacy... What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are the FAT filesystem on your EFI System Partition (ESP) is damaged. This is common on Windows 8 and later dual-boot systems, since Windows now doesn't shut down by default -- instead, it hibernates. Thus, you need to disable Hibernation and the related Fast Startup options, as described here:

- http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html
- http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html

After you disable those features, you may need to fix the filesystem by using `dosfsck` in Ubuntu or equivalent tools in Windows. In extreme cases, you may need to back up the partition, create a fresh FAT filesystem on it (with `mkdosfs` or something similar), and restore it. If you do this, you may need to edit the "UUID" (really a serial number) for the ESP in `/etc/fstab`.

Note that problems like this sometimes crop up in one environment (Windows, Linux, UEFI) but not another because each environment has its own drivers that may respond differently to filesystem damage. In practice, many EFIs have pretty weak FAT drivers that seem to react badly to damage, or sometimes even to filesystems that Windows and Linux say are fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To be honest, I was impacient since I couldn't boot normally, made a backup and created a new fat partition. I had disabled the Windows fast boot hibernation thing, but maybe I accidentally used normal hibernation. Whatever it was, setting up a new efi partition fixed it.